# How can I write my for loop and reg query to return data containing spaces?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

When I run the following in a batch file:

```
for /F "tokens=3" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 3990" /v "InstallLocation" 2^>nul') DO (SET INSTALL_LOCATION=%%A)
```

The value of `INSTALL_LOCATION` is `C:\Program`, rather than an expected value of `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization IV Warlords`.

I think this is a problem with my for loop as opposed to `reg query`, and also I suspect it is caused by the data for that key containing spaces.

How can I get the expected value, please?

My OS is Windows 11 and the script is being executed in CMD.

Thanks!

Comment: Change `"tokens=3"` to `"tokens=2,*"`, then change `(SET INSTALL_LOCATION=%%A)` to `SET "INSTALL_LOCATION=%%B"`.

Comment: @Compo So my code looked like this: `for /F "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 3990" /v "InstallLocation" 2^>nul') DO "SET INSTALL_LOCATION=%%B"`

Comment: The last line of the output from your 'Command' should be `InstallLocation REG_SZ C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization IV Warlords` and as such 'Token 2' _(`%%A`)_, will be propagated with `REG_SZ` and 'Token *', _(`%%B`)_ will be propagated with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Sid Meier's Civilization IV Warlords`.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for your help, but when I run the commands `for /F "tokens=2,*" %%A in ('reg query "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Steam App 3990" /v "InstallLocation" 2^>nul') DO "SET INSTALL_LOCATION=%%B"` then `ECHO %%B` I get `'"SET INSTALL_LOCATION=3990"' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
%B` This is a bit of a mess.

Comment: Watch the position of the quotes. it's `SET "...`, not `"SET ...` (SO convention : `set "var=value"` ensures that trailing spaces are not included in the value assigned.)

Comment: Since your `echo %%B` is outside the `for` loop's scope, you get the literal `%B` but `%` needs to be escaped, so `%%` is required to `echo` "%" Try `echo %install_location%`

Comment: @Magoo Thank you, it works perfectly!

Comment: @Compo it was not wrong, it worked and it was my fault. Thank you very much!